# Eloquent select from array in the same order

Tags: sql, arrays, select, eloquent

I have this eloquent call:

```
$array = [100, 200, 50, 3, 300];
$response = EloquentModel::whereIn('id', $array)->get();
```

but now I want the results to be order in the same order in which the array is ordered; so the result should be like:

```
0 => Obj(
    [id] => 100
    [name] => name100
)
1 => Obj(
    [id] => 200
    [name] => name200
)
2 => Obj(
    [id] => 50
    [name] => name50
)
3 => Obj(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => name3
)
....
```

The order is specified by how the $array variable has it's elements ordered...

Is it possible to do something like that in Eloquent?

Comment: Without using db:row..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the solution is as follow:

```
        $response = EloquentModel::whereIn('id', $array)->get()->sortBy(function($item, $index) use($array){
            $arrayToSortBy = array_flip($array);
            return $arrayToSortBy[$item->id];
    });
```

Basically we can sort [Eloquent:Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-sort) response.

`array_flip` will flip keys with values, so that we can return the relevant number for ordering....

Comment: Thanks for this - it's a much better option than the alternatives I've found.